# How to get around or solve this delegate event issue?

Tags: c#

```
namespace Rocket.Common
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;

    public class SharedProperties
    {
        public static bool snapEnabled = false;
        public static float snapValue = 0.25f;
        public static bool useAxisConstraints = true;

        public static  event PushToGridEventHandler PushToGridEvent
        {
            add
            {
                PushToGridEventHandler pushToGridEvent = PushToGridEvent;
                while (true)
                {
                    PushToGridEventHandler a = pushToGridEvent;
                    PushToGridEventHandler handler3 = (PushToGridEventHandler) Delegate.Combine(a, value);
                    pushToGridEvent = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PushToGridEvent, handler3, a);
                    if (ReferenceEquals(pushToGridEvent, a))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                PushToGridEventHandler pushToGridEvent = PushToGridEvent;
                while (true)
                {
                    PushToGridEventHandler source = pushToGridEvent;
                    PushToGridEventHandler handler3 = (PushToGridEventHandler) Delegate.Remove(source, value);
                    pushToGridEvent = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PushToGridEvent, handler3, source);
                    if (ReferenceEquals(pushToGridEvent, source))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void PushToGrid(float snapValue)
        {
            if (PushToGridEvent != null)
            {
                PushToGridEvent(snapValue);
            }
        }

        public delegate void PushToGridEventHandler(float snapValue);
    }
}
```

CAN SOMEONE HELP ME AS TO SOLVE THE MYSTERY AROUND THIS. I cant seem to get my head around this error.

I am Getting Error on the following lines;

1. (16,58): error CS0079: The event `Rocket.Common.SharedProperties.PushToGridEvent` can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=` operator
2. (21,71): error CS0079: The event `Rocket.Common.SharedProperties.PushToGridEvent` can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=` operator
3. (30,58): error CS0079: The event `Rocket.Common.SharedProperties.PushToGridEvent` can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=` operator
4. (35,71): error CS0079: The event `Rocket.Common.SharedProperties.PushToGridEvent` can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=` operator
5. (46,17): error CS0079: The event `Rocket.Common.SharedProperties.PushToGridEvent` can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=` operator
6. (48,17): error CS0079: The event `Rocket.Common.SharedProperties.PushToGridEvent` can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=` operator

Its the same error again and again. I have searched on the net and there are lots of explanation's on this error but i cant seem to find the right one. OR i am just having a very bad day :)

please help me out

Comment: to add event handlers you should use '+=' opeator, not '='

Comment: i am trying really hard to use '+=' this. But still getting the same error again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have declared `add` and `remove`, to make your code work you have to declare a backing field (private) just like when you use `get` and/or `set` and then you'll be able to invoke using this private field.

So you should have something looking like this

```
namespace Rocket.Common
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;

    public class SharedProperties
    {
        public static bool snapEnabled = false;
        public static float snapValue = 0.25f;
        public static bool useAxisConstraints = true;

        private static event PushToGridEventHandler _pushToGridEvent;
        public static event PushToGridEventHandler PushToGridEvent
        {
            add
            {   
                PushToGridEventHandler pushToGridEvent = _pushToGridEvent;
                while (true)
                {
                    PushToGridEventHandler a = pushToGridEvent;
                    PushToGridEventHandler handler3 = (PushToGridEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(a, value);
                    pushToGridEvent = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _pushToGridEvent, handler3, a);
                    if (ReferenceEquals(pushToGridEvent, a))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                PushToGridEventHandler pushToGridEvent = _pushToGridEvent;
                while (true)
                {
                    PushToGridEventHandler source = pushToGridEvent;
                    PushToGridEventHandler handler3 = (PushToGridEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(source, value);
                    pushToGridEvent = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _pushToGridEvent, handler3, source);
                    if (ReferenceEquals(pushToGridEvent, source))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void PushToGrid(float snapValue)
        {
            _pushToGridEvent?.Invoke(snapValue);
        }
    }

    public delegate void PushToGridEventHandler(float snapValue);
}
```

Comment: error CS1644: Feature `null propagating operator' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification (_pushToGridEvent?.Invoke(snapValue);)

Comment: just replace `_pushToGridEvent?.Invoke(snapValue);` by
`if (_pushToGridEvent != null) _pushToGridEvent.Invoke(snapValue);` or upgrade you project version. It looks like you're using Unity, if so just update Unity to version 2018.3.0 or above and the error will disapear

Comment: Thanks a Lot nalka, seriously i need to go to sleep :). Much appreciated.